# how to unselect all my checkbox

Tags: java, android

I'm trying without success to unselect all my checkbox picks

by pressing any button that in my java android program with this code

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id)
 {
        parent.setItemChecked(position, parent.isItemChecked(position));
 }


 @Override
 protected  Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle args){
    switch(id){
    case 1:
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setTitle("This is a dialog with some simple text...")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"OK clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }})

        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Cancel clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            })

        .setMultiChoiceItems(items, itemsChecked, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),items[which] + (isChecked ? " checked!":" unchecked!"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            })
        .create();
        }
        return(null);
    }
```

how to select all and unselect all ?

Comment: duplicate of [How to uncheck the items while selecting one from ListView Dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155548/how-to-uncheck-the-items-while-selecting-one-from-listview-dialog)

Answer (score 2):

Well, my best guess is to save a reference for all of them on a list, and go through all of them selecting or unselecting them all. Something like this.

Crete a reference to hold all your checkboxes

```
List<CheckBox> myCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
myCheckBoxes.add(cb1);
myCheckBoxes.add(cb2);
myCheckBoxes.add(cb3);
....
```

Create a method that will get the value you want to set on the check boxes and call it whenever you want.
:

```
private checkAll(boolean value) {
    for(CheckBox cb : myCheckBoxes) {
        cb.setChecked(value);
    }
}
```

Create two buttons:

```
Button unselectAllButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.unCheckButton);
Button selectAllButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkButton);

unselectAllButton.setOnClickListener(setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
       checkAll(false); 
   }
});

selectAllButton.setOnClickListener(setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
       checkAll(true); 
   }
});
```

Comment: can i get any sample for this ?

Comment: thanks for the help, I am pretty new in android.... can you update my code With your solution ?

Comment: Looking at your code once more, I consider you want to check your checkboxes on the onListItemclick. There, call the checkAll method with the boolean you want. Make the list a field of the class, and instantiate it on the beginning of "onCreate() (and add all the checkboxes, you have on xml layout (or created programatically)".

Comment: I can't make it all for you because I don't know everything you are trying to accomplish. I just posted the most part, either you write everything you want to do and post your code or I can't help you any more.

Comment: Thanks again for the help, i need simple solution for uncheck all of the checkbox. In my program i made a button that clear all the selected checkbox but i cant do it

Comment: its not work, all my checkbox created in the dialog how i can Crete a reference to hold all my checkboxes ?  what is the meaning of: myCheckBoxes.add(cb1); ho is cd1 ?